# Parsing Django Queryset JSON

Tags: jquery, python, django

I want to parse a query set to output json data. However I need to make it so that the new jquery ui autocomplete can use it too, and the autocomplete needs the keys `label`, `id` and `value` to be able to read it.

Currently I use:

```
    emp_list = Employees.objects.filter(eng_name__icontains=q_term)

    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
    json_data = json_serializer.serialize
           (emp_list, ensure_ascii=False, fields=('eng_name', 'chi_name'))
```

and the output is something like

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "system.employees", 
"fields": {"rank": "manager", "eng_name": "Eli"}}, 
........]
```

I want to be able to parse it into something like this instead:

```
[{"id": 1, "label": "Eli (manager)", "value": "Eli (manager)"}, ....]
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build it in your view then json dump it

```
employees_output_list = []
for emp in emp_list:
  name_rank_str = "%s (%s)" % (emp.first_name, emp.rank)
  emp_dict = {
    "id": emp.pk,
    "label": name_rank_str,
    "value": name_rank_str,
  }
  employees_output_list.append(emp_dict)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(employees_output_list))
```

something like this, don't know your actual field names